# PostgreSQL Lock Row on indefinitely time

Tags: atomic, postgresql-9.2, interlocked

I wanna lock one row by some user until he work with this row on indefinitely time and he must unlock it when done. So any others users will not be able to lock this row for yourself. It is possible to do on data base level?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a long-lived transaction, but there'll be performance issues with that. This sounds like more of a job for optimistic concurrency control.

You *can* just open a transaction and do a `SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE clause to match row FOR UPDATE;`. Then keep the transaction open until you're done. The problem with this is that it can cause issues with vacuum that result in table and index bloat, where tables get filled with deleted data and indexes fill up with entries pointing to obsolete blocks.

It'd be much better to use an [advisory lock](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS). You still have to hold the connection the holds the lock open, but it doesn't have to keep an open idle transaction, so it's much lower impact. Transactions that wish to update the row must explicitly check for a conflicting advisory lock, though, otherwise they can just proceed as if it wasn't locked. This approach also scales poorly to lots of tables (due to limited advisory lock namespace) or lots of concurrent locks (due to number of connections).

You can use a trigger to check for the advisory lock and wait for it if you can't make sure your client apps will always get the advisory lock explicitly. However, this can create deadlock issues.

For that reason, the best approach is probably to have a `locked_by` field that records a user ID, and a `locked_time` field that records when it was locked. Do it at the application level and/or with triggers. To deal with concurrent attempts to obtain the lock you can use [optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) techniques, where the `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` that sets `locked_by` and `locked_time` will not match if someone else gets there first, so the rowcount will be zero and you'll know you lost the race for the lock and have to re-check. That `WHERE` clause usually tests `locked_by` and `locked_time`. So you'd write something like:

```
UPDATE t
SET locked_by = 'me' AND locked_time = current_timestamp
WHERE locked_by IS NULL AND locked_time IS NULL
AND id = [ID of row to update];
```

(This is a simplified optimistic locking mode for grabbing a lock, where you don't mind if someone else jumped in and did an entire transaction. If you want stricter ordering, you use a row-version column or you check that a last_modified column hasn't changed.)

Comment: look like query update all rows where "locked_by IS NULL AND locked_time IS NULL", but how about update only one row? And i think can be a situation when application is falling and row stay locked, it's OK but when user restart the program a row where locked_by = 'me' would already exist so he need to take it first. PS sorry for my english

Comment: @Miles Yes, rather. Should've included the ID of interest. Fixed.

Comment: @Miles As for app failing, you can't easily have "unlock automatically on crash" at the same time as "locked indefinitely". You'll probably have to rely on an open TCP connection to PostgreSQL, either advisory locking or long running tx (but long running tx's are really bad if the DB is under much write load).